# Проблема с обращением к локальному файлу linux, через Django

Tags: linux, django, файловые-пути

Проблема: когда пытаюсь получить данные из локального файла в linux, через view.py - request.GET.get метод - получаю ошибку кодировки.

Файл view.py - в нем нет проблем JS передает корректные данные, которые передаются в функцию find_duty в качестве аргумента:

```
def test_page(request):  
    ...  
    duty_get = request.GET.get('findDuty')
    if duty_get is not None:
        try:
            duty = find_duty(duty_get)
        except Exception as e:
            duty = json.dumps([{'error': str(e)}])
        finally:
            return HttpResponse(duty, content_type="application/json")
        
    return render(request, 'siteapp/test.html', context)
```

Файл содержащий def find_duty(t):

```
...
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(f'/path/to/file/График.xlsx')
...
return json.dumps(result)
```

На выходе прилетает ошибка:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 22-27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Проблема в названии кириллицей, а именно слове График, меняю его на 1 или test, все работает ок, но поменять его и забыть не могу, т.к. файл мапится из windows. Гуглю 3 дня тему с encode, пробовал декодировать название файла и передавать его в функцию, где пытался указать кодировку - не сработало. Так же для меня загадка, почему, когда я запускаю функцию напрямую в print прилетает, то что я ожидаю, без смены График на что либо.